# Detect missing null guards in CI or earlier with PHP

Tags: php

I have an aging PHP app. As some more modern code has been introduced we're gradually hitting more cases where a type signature is causing a fatal error for a miss handled null that might not have even caused a warning in previous versions.

E.g:

```php
<?php
function mightReturnName(): ?string {
    return rand(0, 1) ? "Fred" : null;
}
function getHello(string $name): string {
    return "Hello $name";
}
echo getHello(mightReturnName())."\n";
```

50% of the time this will correctly print `Hello Fred`, e.g:

```
$ php test.php
Hello Fred
```

however, the introduction of the `string` type in the signature of `getHello()` causes a fatal error:

```
$ php test.php
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to getHello() must be of the type string, null given, called in /tmp/test.php on line 8 and defined in /tmp/test.php:5
Stack trace:
#0 /tmp/test.php(8): getHello(NULL)
#1 {main}
  thrown in /tmp/test.php on line 5
```

where previously we would just display a shortened greeting without even a warning:

```
$ php test.php
Hello
```

Are there any code linters, SAST or other alternatives that detect the use of a nullable type without a suitable guard and warn about it so this can be detected in CI and not, in the worst case, production?

Comment: Wouldn't that be nice if there was.

Answer (score 0):

[PHPStan](https://phpstan.org/) can detect the problem:

```
$ phpstan analyse -l 8 -- ./test.php
 1/1 [▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓] 100%

 ------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Line   test.php                                                                    
 ------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  8      Parameter #1 $name of function getHello expects string, string|null given.  
 ------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 


                                                                                                                        
 [ERROR] Found 1 error
```

and if I change the last line to guard against the `null` e.g:

```php
echo getHello(mightReturnName() ?? '')."\n";
```

PHPStan reports no errors.